# angular 2 material how i can set md slide nav's height to 100% (whole screen)?

Tags: css, angular2-material

i am using   **"@angular2-material/sidenav": "2.0.0-alpha.6-2",** and i have bootstrap menu that i want to switch to md-slidenav in mobile so i was able to hide my bootstrap menu in screens less then 768 px and show my md -slidenav but it is somehow inherit menu height and does not show for whole screen.

```
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default  switch" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
    aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">
    <img class="logo" src="{{imgPath}}" />
  </a>

</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right pull oa-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <span class="list-land">
          link
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/link']">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/user/sign-in']">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary join-now" style=" margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 8px; " [routerLink]="['/user/signup']">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" [routerLink]="['/aboutus/welcome']">Welcome Letter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" [routerLink]="['/aboutus/news']">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" [routerLink]="['/aboutus/help']">Help</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
      <md-sidenav-layout  >   
<div class="left-menu">
  <button class="hamburger" (click)="left.toggle()">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
 </button>
</div>

<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav tab-toggle" #left (open)="mybutton.focus()"  mode="over" layout-padding>
  <button #mybutton (click)="left.close()" class="btn" style="right:20px;top:10px;
          position:absolute;
          padding: 0px 4px;
          border-radius: 10px;
          border-color:#fff;">
    <i  class="fa fa-times fa-2x" style="color:#009688;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div>
    <ul class="list-item">
         <li>
          <a  [routerLink]="['/profile/my-excursions']">My Trips</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a  [routerLink]="['/profile/membership']">Membership</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="userService.isMember">
          <a [routerLink]="['/profile/background-check']">Background Check</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a  [routerLink]="['/user/change-password']">Password</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a  (click)="logOut()">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul> </div>
</md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

also i tried to add fullscreen directive to md-slide-layout tag but it didnt work either

Comment: If you want to utilize the browser window, you can use view port points.. view port height VH and view port width VW.. The best thing about view port points are responsive.. it adapts to every screen.. you don't need to write media queries.. and view ports can also be used in other HTML elements.. if you want to make your font size responsive with all screen sizes without writing media queries? Give view port points to font-size.. with view ports you can do so many awesome things..

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport units (vh) instead of percentages. Since 1 vh equals 1% of the browser's window height, then 100 vh would be the same as writing 100%. And the most important thing: it works with Angular 2 (I've just had the same issue).